# What is the scoping logic behind React states being used inside functions in custom hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, scoping

So say you have a custom hook:

```
useCustomHook()=>{
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  
  const modifyState = ({state, n}) => {setState(state + n);} 
  
  /*Does state need to be included as an argument/parameter here in modifyState? If, alternatively, 
    
   const modifyState = ({n}) => {setState(state + n)};

   Will state always be 0 in the scope of modifyState, since that was its value when the function was 
   created originally. So everytime modifyState is called, it is equivalent to (n)=>setState(0+n) ?
 */
  
  return [state, modifyState];
}

const FunctionalComponent = () => {
   const [state, modifyState] = useCustomHook(); 
   const n = 5;
   modifyState({state,n}) /* Does state need to be passed here? (since useCustomHook already has its own 
                             copy of state) */

  //... logic ....

  return <div></div>


}
```

From doing some testing in the console, it appears that `state` doesn't need to be passed as an argument to `modifyState`. But, I'm confused as to the scoping logic behind this, and am unsure if the behavior hooks would change it. Could someone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Tangential point: you might want to memoize `modifyState` or your `useCustomHook` is going to be a _lot_ less useful than [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), which you might want to look into first before you go down the path of trying to write your own custom hook.

Comment: Is that because state is an argument to modifyState or the example I used? This is just a simplified version to show the scope logic.

Comment: No, it's because `modifyState` is just an arrow function, whose reference will change on each render, which means that it's less useful than the memoized `setState` or `dispatch` provided by the builtin `useState` and `useReducer` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the state you can make use of function implementation of `setState`. Something like this:

```
const modifyState = (n) => {
   setState(state => state + n);
}
```

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that method. Though I just used modifyState as a simplified example of the structure. My question is about the logic of the scope and whether state is needed as an argument.